# How can I make ahoy's javascript asynchronous function track synchronous

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, rubygems, ahoy

I have some code which calls a function like this :

```
function trackPDFSEClicks(){
        ahoy.track("Viewed Job Spec", {title: "Viewed Software Engineer Job Spec"});
        window.location.href = "/Software Engineer.pdf";
    }
```

However because this track call is asynchronous - sometimes it doesn't complete before the PDF has loaded - and therefore the event is not tracked.

I do not necessarily want to have to go and handle this tracking in the controller as it would be far simpler for me to use this method if possible - so is there any way I can force this ahoy.track call to be run synchronously?

Comment: based on the code, I doubt it. https://github.com/ankane/ahoy.js/blob/master/ahoy.js#L214-L231 Silly it doesnt provide callback or promise chain

Comment: Agreed - thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

I decided after apneadiving's insight to just create an action in my controller for each of my downloadable links - and used the rails API from ahoy combined with the rails `send_file` method - which gives me the kind of behaviour I expect.